# проверка строки на число

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw

пытаюсь реализовать функцию по проверки числа в виде строки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool CheckingNumbers(const string&);

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    string s1 = "123";
    string s2 = "asd";
    string s3 = "123asd";
    string s4 = "asd123";

    cout << CheckingNumbers(s1) << endl;
    cout << CheckingNumbers(s2) << endl;
    cout << CheckingNumbers(s3) << endl;
    cout << CheckingNumbers(s4) << endl;


        return 0;
}

bool CheckingNumbers(const string& s) {
    bool b = true;
    for (auto& a : s) {
        if (!iswalnum(a)) {
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return b;
};
```

должно по идее выводить

```
1
0
0
0
```

но что то идет не так, что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: а что не так то? первая строка число, остальное - нет.

Comment: выводит четыре единицы

Comment: Не уверен, но все же проверьте, Вам нужна именно функция iswalnum, или же isalnum?

Comment: Подозреваючто вам нужен std::iswdigit, а не std::iswalnum

Comment: и тот и другой вариант(iswalnum, isalnum) выводят то же самое

Comment: @Jester, похоже, это ответ :)) ему же число нужно , а проверяет совсем другое :))

Comment: Jester спасибо помогло )

Comment: @Jester, ответы в ответы.

Comment: Без осмысленного объяснения, почему автор вообще полез в `isalnum`, ценность вопроса равна нулю. Это фактически опечатка. Также отсутствует описание того, что именно нужно сделать. `-5` - это "число" или не "число"? Не "в ответы", а закрыть вопрос.

Comment: [man strtoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool isNumber(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](const char& ch) { return isdigit(ch); });
}
```

Comment: А лямбда тут зачем?

Comment: Akkur Dev, Visual C++ 2019, пишет что (std::all_of) namespace std не содержит члена all_of

Comment: @NIkolai, нужно подключить заголовок.  `#include <algorithm>`